# Unhandled error when opening Internet Explorer 8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I get such an error when I open IE8 in Windows 7 32-bit machine:

```
An unhandled exception ( Unknown runtime error ) occurred in iexplore.exe [4736]
```

and a Microsoft Visual Debugger starts up.

Any suggestions or help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is solved. Might have been a possible problem with the third party toolbars and some addons. The issue stopped after I removed those toolbars and addons.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of BHOs (Browser Helper Objects) is causing this error. They are DLLs (COM objects) loaded by iexplore.exe into its address space at startup. Try disabling IE BHOs using [WhatsInStartup](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/what_run_in_startup.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Nothing was there that WhatsInStartup could do.  But i followed the clue from your answer to check with the addons and other toolbars installed on that . removed all of them and it started working. Anyway thanks :)